# POSIX signal behavior

Tags: c, posix, signals, kill

If a process is currently stopped due to a SIGTRAP signal and it is sent a SIGSTOP signal via kill(), what would be the default behavior? Would the SIGSTOP be a pending signal that is delivered after the process continues again? Or will it just be discarded/ignored?

If the SIGSTOP is queued up, is there any way to remove it from the queue from outside of that process, such as in a tracing process?

Comment: I haven't been able to dig up an authoritative answer.  The OpenBSD man pages hint at what might happen, but don't definitively answer it one way or the other.  See http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sigaction&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html and http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sigsuspend&sektion=2&arch=i386&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the signal(7) man page:

```
The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.
```

A simple test with an app stopped on a breakpoint and sending it a `SIGSTOP` shows gdb displaying some information when I hit 'next'.  The signal was obviously delivered to the app.  It cannot continue to be debugged until I send it a `SIGCONT`.

```
(gdb) next
Program received signal SIGSTOP, Stopped (signal).
fill (arr=0x7fffffffdff0, size=5) at tmp.cpp:28
(gdb) next
Program received signal SIGCONT, Continued.
fill (arr=0x7fffffffdff0, size=5) at tmp.cpp:28
(gdb) next
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'stopped due to a SIGTRAP signal'?  A SIGTRAP will not stop a process; by default it will terminate with a core dump, or you can change it to ignore the signal or call a signal handler, but in no case will the SIGTRAP stop the process by itself.  You might have the process being traced by some other process (such as a debugger) with ptrace(2), in which case it will stop just before delivering the SIGTRAP, but in that case its under the control of the ptrace and won't continue until there's a PTRACE_CONT or other ptrace action to continue the process.

Comment: I am tracing another process and acting as a debugger, so when the process hits a breakpoint it will be delivered a SIGTRAP and the process is stopped. So I just want to know if it is stopped and has that SIGTRAP signal delivered, what will happen if following that a SIGSTOP is delivered to the process? Will it be pending or will it just be discarded since the process is already stopped?